# nagios send notification until acknowledgement passive checks

Tags: nagios

I  have a setup where nagios receives a snmp trap from a device. It then notifies the contact defined in config.cfg. that works great. What I am trying to accomplish is have nagios send another notification if the problem isn't acknowledge in a given amount of time. I can not get nagios to send that second notification. I am using external commands to actually make a call as the notification, that all works fine. I don't see nagios attempt to make that second notification.

I cut down all my config files to 1 config file for easy of reading.

```
  #TIMEPERIODS


  define timeperiod{
    timeperiod_name 24x7
    alias           24 Hours A Day, 7 Days A Week
    sunday          00:00-24:00
    monday          00:00-24:00
    tuesday         00:00-24:00
    wednesday       00:00-24:00
    thursday        00:00-24:00
    friday          00:00-24:00
    saturday        00:00-24:00
    }

  #SERVICES


  ##handle the trap


  define service{
    host_name                       serverName
    service_description             TRAP
    is_volatile                     1
    check_command                   check-host-alive
    max_check_attempts              3
    normal_check_interval           1
    retry_check_interval            1
    active_checks_enabled           0
    passive_checks_enabled          1
    check_period                    24x7
    notification_interval           1
    notification_period             24x7
    notification_options            w,u,c
    notifications_enabled           1
    contact_groups                  admins
    }

  #COMMANDS

  define command{
    command_name    check-host-alive
    command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
    }

  define command{
    command_name  notify-host-by-sip
    command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/calls/makeCall "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$"
  }

  define command{
    command_name notify-service-by-sip
    command_line /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/calls/makeCall "$NOTIFICATIONTYPE$"


  }



  #CONTACT_GROUPS

  define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name       admins
    alias                   Nagios Administrators
    members                 user_sip
    }

  #CONTACTS 

  define contact{
    contact_name  user_sip
    alias  useralias
    service_notification_period  24x7
    host_notification_period  24x7
    service_notification_options  w
    host_notification_options  d
    service_notification_commands notify-service-by-sip
    host_notification_commands  notify-host-by-sip
    email  someNumber@someServer
  }

  #HOSTS

  define host{
    host_name                       localhost
    alias                           Development
    address                         serverIP
    max_check_attempts              5
    check_period                    24x7
    contact_groups                  admins
    notification_period             24x7
    }

  define host{
    host_name                      serverName
    alias                           Development
    address                         someIP
    max_check_attempts              5
    check_period                    24x7
    contact_groups                  admins
    notification_period             24x7
    }
```

results of passive check

```
 [1386274600] PASSIVE SERVICE CHECK: localhost;TRAP;1;TRAP trap received
 [1386274600] SERVICE ALERT: localhost;TRAP;WARNING;HARD;1;TRAP trap received
 [1386274600] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: user_sip;localhost;TRAP;WARNING;notify-service-by-sip;TRAP trap received
```

and then nothing after that...

Comment: I do not see a serviceescalation defined?  An ACK would stop notifications, even the escalated ones.

Comment: @JimBlack   I am only getting 1 notification.  if a problem happens I want notifications to occur repeatedly until acknowledgement. right now, I get 1 trap, 1 notification, and thats it.  if i miss that notification, i will not know the problem occured....

Comment: OK.  On the GUI (or in status.dat), is the service still showing as being down after the first notification?

Comment: yes. it stays in warning forever unless I send a passive check.

Comment: Can you include a copy of your passive check output, both 'good' and 'bad'?  This would be the text going into the 'external commands file'.

Comment: edited original post,  is that what you are looking for?

Comment: It should begin with 'PROCESS_HOST_CHECK_RESULT' or 'PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT'.

Comment: in /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/eventhandlers/submit_check_result  i find    

cmdline="[$datetime] PROCESS_SERVICE_CHECK_RESULT;$1;$2;$3;$4"

Answer (score 3):

After looking though the Nagios source I can say:

- Notifications will only ever happen **after** a check result has been processed (active or passive).  It will throw a warning on start up, if you attempt to set the 'notification_interval' to a value less than the 'check_interval'.
- If you set 'is_volatile' to '1', this will ignore all 'notification_interval' options in the tree.  This basically means, send a notification **every time a check fails**.  But the check must still fail, before a notification will be sent.

So if the passive check is not *actively* throwing non-OK results, you will not get a constant flow of alerts.

A work-around for this behavior is to create an 'event-handler' script that would:

1. Check that the Nagios macro $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ is not equal to "ACKNOWLEDGEMENT" (you must be sure that ACK notifications are enabled).
2. If above is true, sleep for 59 seconds, then resubmit the same passive check failure, with a new epoch time stamp, to the Nagios external command file.

This should keep the alerts going until they are ACK'd by someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a script as you suggest, but what happens when the clear trap comes in there is a still a sleeping event timer that resubmits the previous failed trap. Also nagios event handler hangs for the event of the sleep timer with and without &

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICESTATE=$1
HOSTADDRESS=$2
SERVICEDESC=$3
SERVICEOUTPUT=$4
NOTIFICATIONTYPE=$5

if [ $NOTIFICATIONTYPE == 'ACKNOWLEDGEMENT' ]
then exit
fi
case "$SERVICESTATE" in
        OK)
                rm /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad
                exit
                ;;
        WARNING)
                touch /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad
                sleep 45
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                sh /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 1 $SERVICEOUTPUT
                fi
                exit
                ;;
        CRITCAL)
                touch /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad
                sleep 45
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                sh /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 2 "$SERVICEOUTPUT"
                fi
                exit
                ;;
        UNKNOWN)
                exit
                ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed it around abit, Have my snmp trap handler executing a script that touches a file and on a timer if that file exists it will resend the check result to nagios.

I use these to delay the first notification so quick problems and recovery do not wake me at night and to repeat the notifications. Since Nagios decides if it should notifcate or not, if you acknowledge the issue you don't receive emails anymore.

excuse my bad coding, I learned just to solve this issue... :P

pass2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# VER 2 
HOSTADDRESS=$1
SERVICEDESC=$2
SERVICESTATE=$3
SERVICEOUTPUT=$4

case "$SERVICESTATE" in
        0)
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                rm /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 0 "$4"
                fi
                exit
                ;;
        1)
                touch /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 1 "$4" &
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/passtron.sh $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 1 "$4" &
                fi
                exit
                ;;
        2)
                touch /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 2 "$4" &
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/passtron.sh $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 2 "$4" &
                fi
                exit
                ;;
        UNKNOWN)
                exit
                ;;
esac
```

passtron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# PASSTRON
HOSTADDRESS=$1
SERVICEDESC=$2
SERVICESTATE=$3
SERVICEOUTPUT=$4

case "$SERVICESTATE" in
        1)
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                sleep 60
                fi
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 1 "$4" &
                fi
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/passtron.sh $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 1 "$4" &
                fi
                exit
                ;;
        2)
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                sleep 60
                fi
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/submit_check_result $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 2 "$4" &
                fi
                if [ -f /usr/local/libexec/nagios/pass/$HOSTADDRESS.$SERVICEDESC.bad ]
                then
                /usr/local/libexec/nagios/passtron.sh $HOSTADDRESS $SERVICEDESC 2 "$4" &
                fi
                exit
                ;;

esac
```

and example of one of my service

```
define service{
 hostgroup_name         trapdevices
 use                    trap-template
 service_description    TEMP-ALARM
 contact_groups          oncall-tech
 is_volatile 0
 normal_check_interval 1
 retry_check_interval  1
 max_check_attempts    1
 active_checks_enabled 0
 notification_interval 300
 first_notification_delay 5
```